# C++ How to Trigger Class Destructor

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I'm developing a class to process config files, which consist of a number of segments, each segment with a number of key:value elements. I have the following code (pared down to just the basic issue):

```
class cfgElement {
    public:
        char       *key;
        char       *val;
        cfgElement *link;

        cfgElement() {
            key = nullptr;
            val = nullptr;
            link = nullptr;
        }

       ~cfgElement() {
            if (key != nullptr) delete key;
            if (val != nullptr) delete val;
            key  = nullptr;
            val  = nullptr;
            link = nullptr;
        }
};

struct cfgSegment {
    char        Name[16];
    cfgElement  head;
};

class config {
    private:
        cfgSegment *segments;

    public:
        config() {
            segments = new cfgSegment[5];
        }

       ~config() {
           for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
               // Clean up segments[i].head
           }
       }
};
```

If I declare a `cfgElement` in the main code, it of course triggers the destructor as expected. Those which are part of the `segments[]` array do not get triggered when the `config` object goes out of scope, and I can understand why not, but is there a way to get the `cfgElement` destructor to trigger for those? I can't `delete` them, as they are not pointers.

I could make the `head` element of `cfgSegment` a pointer, and loop over the `segments[]` array in the `config` constructor, allocating each `cfgElement` individually, but is that the only way to do it?

Comment: does `delete[] segments;` work? Inside `~config()` without a for loop.

Comment: Please learn to use std::string instead of char*, and smart pointers (u.e. std::unique_ptr) instad of "raw" pointer, your development life will be easier.

Comment: @roalz Yes, I understand strings and smart pointers are easier to use, but as I'm learning, I want to to do things the hard way, so that I understand these issues.

Comment: @alanlittle Great point and I agree. Maybe better to add that info in your question next time.

Comment: @roalz Will do, thanks.

Comment: @GaryJohnson Yes -- see answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just to delete segments instead of deleting each object in the loop.

```
   ~config() {
         delete[] segments;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought I tried that before, and the compiler complained about `delete`ing an array. However, your solution works as advertised. Thanks!

Comment: `delete` works with single objects, `delete[]` works with arrays. Actually both variants should work, but `delete` on an array will cause a memory leak.

Comment: Actually, what I tried before, in `main()` was just `int x[5]; delete[] x;` and the compiler said `[Warning] deleting array 'x'`. I'm not sure what the difference is, putting it in the destructor; as far as I can see, it's essentially the same thing. Ah -- nevermind, I see the difference. `segments[]` is indeed dynamically allocated.

Comment: @GoverNator "Actually both variants should work, but delete on an array will cause a memory leak". False and false. `delete` works only with `new` and `delete[]` works only with `new[]`. Using them with the wrong counterpart causes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @bolov I mean, it would compile, and run succesfully, but incorrect.

Comment: nitpicking: if it runs incorrect, then it doesn't run successfully, does it? (I understand what you tried to say) More serious matter: "delete on an array will cause a memory leak" this is simply false and dangerous to say to someone who is learning about these matters. That will cause Undefined Behavior. That means that is can continue to run with a memory leak, continue to run and delete the array, continue to run and corrupt the heap (and crash at a later time), crash on spot or any other behavior you can think of.

Comment: @bolov Thank's for explanation. I've already found out some proofs.

Comment: @GoverNator when you say `delete`ing an array will cause a memory leak, does this apply to vectors as well?

Comment: @JacobSchneider do you mean std::vector?

Comment: @GoverNator Yes, I'm thinking of std::vector

Comment: Then the answer is no. Vector is a resource handler, so it calls destructors of the stored objects, on erasing/replacing etc. But it's quite ofter when the vector stores pointers to some objects, but deleting pointer doesn't mean deleting the object which is being pointed at.